# "Classical" description of automorphic forms on unitary groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, automorphic-forms

What I mean by classical: For the case of $GL_2$, the answer to my question would be that the automorphic forms are either Maas forms or modular forms. For $GSp(2n)$ these are the Siegel modular forms.

Are there any "classical" objects which appeared in mathematics before this automorphic perspective which align with automorphic forms on $U(n)$ or other unitary groups?

Maybe its the case that, historically, automorphic forms on unitary groups came first: then the question is: are there any other "models" of these kinds of functions?

Comment: By their L-functions ?

Comment: I have no idea if such a thing exists in the literature, but one way to go about it would be to start with the adèlic picture of automorphic representations of unitary groups and work backwards. For $\mathrm{GL}_2$, this isn't too hard to do once the dictionary between classical automorphic forms on the upper half plane and automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ is fleshed out (and this exists in the literature, more or less, in the books of Gelbart, Bump, and Goldfeld-Hundley).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These go by the name of "Hermitian modular forms". They occur very frequently in papers of Shimura (e.g. his monograph *Arithmeticity on the theory of automorphic forms*) and in other more recent works. For instance, [this paper by Bouganis](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-20/37.pdf) describes in detail at the beginning of section 2 the classical description of Hermitian modular forms for $U(n, n)$, the adelic description, and the passage between the two. There are similar descriptions available for $U(m, n)$ with $m \ne n$ as well.

Comment: Also, Hel Braun had looked at holomorphic automorphic forms on $U(n,n)$ in the 1950s in a style similar to what she and C. Siegel had used c. 1939 in studying holomorphic modular forms on $Sp(n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In many cases they are called Picard modular forms.  They go back to the 1880s.  See Picard, E.: Sur des fontions de deux variables independantes analogues aux fonctions modulaires. Acta Math. 2, 114-135 (1883).